# Cannot Find Module ' Webpack' Bigcommerce

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I am trying to connect to Bigcommerce Stencil. I am able to pull and download but having trouble with pushing as I kept getting a no webpack module error. I have tried several things like google for hours but no lack.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'

Require stack:
- C:\Users\z\downloads\bigcommerce\skeyndor\stencil.conf.js
- C:\Users\z\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\BuildConfigManager.js
- C:\Users\z\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\stencil-start.js
- C:\Users\z\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\bin\stencil-start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\z\downloads\bigcommerce\skeyndor\stencil.conf.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\z\\downloads\\bigcommerce\\skeyndor\\stencil.conf.js',
    'C:\\Users\\z\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@bigcommerce\\stencil-cli\\lib\\BuildConfigManager.js',
    'C:\\Users\\z\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@bigcommerce\\stencil-cli\\lib\\stencil-start.js',
    'C:\\Users\\z\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@bigcommerce\\stencil-cli\\bin\\stencil-start.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of stencil-cli do you have installed? If you update to 6.0.0 is the problem resolved? Looks like they've had issues in the past using insecure git ports in dependencys' pacakge.jsons, for some reason. Same for Cornerstone, if you have an old version of that try bringing it up tot 6.7.0 or something else recent.

Comment: Hi 
My Stencil is Version 6, Node 14

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i --save webpack
```

Try installing webpack or add it to package.json

Comment: Their question said they've tried that.

Comment: They have tried with --save-dev

Comment: At dev time, it doesn't matter whether a dependency is installed as a devDep or regular dep — that only matters when running `npm i --production` or `NODE_ENV=production npm i` — and also, webpack and other build tools _are_ for development time, not production.

Comment: Additionally, `npm i` saves by default (to prod deps), unless `--no-save` is provided, since 2017.